# Connection between ios devices

Tags: ios, sockets, xmpp, communication

In our current app we have a server to manage file transfers between ios devices. I want to use our server only to share matched devices (ip addresses of devices may be?) to connect them directly each other.

Is there a way to communicate iOS devices to share files directly or is there only way to use a central server to share files from each other? And how about XMPP ?

Comment: You can use sockets or airdrop feature for iOS 7+ devices.

Comment: I think sockets might be block by some routers or is there a way to solve it with sockets?

Comment: if it blocked by network admin, there is no way to solve it. in that scenario only alternative is bluetooth.